# How to call a function in another function with scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am learning Scheme, so I am doing a program with two functions one calculate how many planes will fly based on the number of people flying and the number of seats on a plane. Until there everything is okay, the problem is when I try to use the function in another one, I don't know how to do it.

First function:

```scm
(define calculate-aeroplanes
  (lambda (passengers seats)
    (ceiling (/ passengers seats))))
```

On the second function I want to put a fee for 1000$ for each plane, if it's less than 11 planes, from the 11th plane the fee will be 500$ , and for each passenger there will be a fee of 50$.

Here what I did:

```scm
(define fee-airport
  (lambda (passengers seats)
    (cond
      ((< calculate-aeroplanes (passengers seats) 11)
       (+ (* calculate-aeroplanes 1000)
          (* passengers 50)))
      ((> calculate-aeroplanes (passengers seats) 10)
       (+ (* calculate-aeroplanes (passengers seats) 10000)
          (* (- calculate-aeroplanes (passengers seats) 10) 500)
          (* passengers 50))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of a function-call in Scheme is `(function-name arguments)`, not `function-name(arguments)`. You use the correct syntax when calling `<`, `+` etc., but not when calling `calculate-aeroplanes`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you are using `+`. `+` is not special by any means, it's just a simple function. To apply a function you just need to put it at the beginning of a form.

```
(calculate-aeroplanes passenger seats)
```

will call the calculate-aeroplanes with the passenger and seats argument)

Comment: Thank you very much, was so simple, just syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Was syntax problems, thanks here is the new code:

```
(define fee-airport
   (lambda(passengers seats)
     (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats)
     (cond
       ((< (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats) 11)
         (+ (* (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats)1000) (* passengers 
            50)))
       ((> (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats) 10)
             (+ (* (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats )10000) (* (- 
             (calculate-aeroplanes passengers seats) 10) 500)  (* passengers 
                   50))))
       )
 )
```